# Worklight - Building iPhone environment

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on Worklight version 6.1.I have created a native ios environment.I added controller classes in the Xcode project and added native functionalities. I have added .js files in the eclipse project.Now I need build my iPhone environment.But I am afraid that native content (Xcode project) will get lost,after building the environment.What is the solution for this.
I should build at the same time native content shouldn't be lost.
How to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation is VERY raw... it doesn't make much sense to me.

> have created a native ios environment

What is that exactly? do you mean that you:

1. Created a Worklight project and added a Native API for iPhone, or
2. Created a Worklight project, added a Hybrid app and then added the iPhone environment to that application
3. Created a fully native project in Xcode?

The distinction between the 3 is important, and you need to mention this in your question **in clear wording**.

If what you mean is that you went with option 2 above, then your JS, CSS and HTML can be either in the common folder or in the environment folder.
If you then want to add native code, you need to first build your project and then open the generated Xcode project in Xcode, write native code and make sure to copy it back to your Worklight project in Eclipse.

> I added controller classes in the Xcode project and added native
>   functionalities

*Where* did you add this? In which file? in the classes provided by Worklight in option 2 above, or in a *new* Class.
Either way, you need to bring these files back into Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you can create a iphone\nativeResources\Classes folder. During build-time in Eclipse, the files in this folder will be copied into the iphone\native\Classes folder, and when opened again in Xcode - your native code will be there...

Note: if you created your own class file, you will need to reference it in Xcode (right-click > add files...). Worklight cannot do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your customizations should not be lost. Have you tried making the build already and your resources were overwritten?